# Is a Ruby global variable different per process?

Tags: ruby, process, global-variables, puma

Is the value of a Ruby global variable different for each process?

For example, if I do `$count = 5`, will that change the value of `$count` on another process?

I'm wondering this because [Puma clustered mode can fork multiple processes (workers)](https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode), and I want to make sure `$count` is unique per worker.

Comment: This actually doesn't have that much to do with Ruby. A process in general is a self-contained isolated environment. Forking is like starting a new program from the command line, the only difference is that you copy the running state of the current process into your new process.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, globals should be unique per process.